# Creating a tensor from matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, tensors

I have 3 nxn matrices that I'd like to combine into a nxnx3 tensor. Basically, I want a new nxn matrix where each element is a 3 tuple of the elements of the other 3 matrices at that same position. What would be the best way of doing this in mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example for `n=3`, using [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html):

```
With[{n = 3}, 
 Transpose[{Array[a, {n, n}], Array[b, {n, n}], Array[c, {n, n}]}, {3, 1, 2}]]

(*
==> {{{a[1, 1], b[1, 1], c[1, 1]}, {a[1, 2], b[1, 2], 
   c[1, 2]}, {a[1, 3], b[1, 3], c[1, 3]}}, {{a[2, 1], b[2, 1], 
   c[2, 1]}, {a[2, 2], b[2, 2], c[2, 2]}, {a[2, 3], b[2, 3], 
   c[2, 3]}}, {{a[3, 1], b[3, 1], c[3, 1]}, {a[3, 2], b[3, 2], 
   c[3, 2]}, {a[3, 3], b[3, 3], c[3, 3]}}}
*)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: The `Flatten[]` version: `Flatten[(* arrays *), {{2}, {3}, {1}}]`